# undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt() CodeBlocks Windows

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

I'm trying to use boost on CodeBlocks. I have codeblocks configured with MinGW-w64. I alredy have included the following libraries in the linker settings

```
libboost_system-mgw73-mt-d-x32-1_66.a
libboost_system-mgw73-mt-x64-1_66.a
libboost_filesystem-mgw73-mt-x64-1_66.dll.a
```

I also try changing the order...

This is the source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if( fs::is_directory("."))
    cout << "Works!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

i have read many "solutions" but they didn't work.
i tried:

- changing the #include for this

  ```
  #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
  #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
  #undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
  ```
- creating a new compiler flag with boths values

```
-lboost_filesystem-mt
```

and also

```
-lboost_filesystem
```

but i always get the same error

```
...\boost_1_66_0\boost\filesystem\path.hpp|981|undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'|
```

Comment: You must link with both libraries, so add to the linker options `-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system`.

Comment: Sorry for the late... I just give it up... I have installed Qt and everything works perfect